# "Edit profile" section throws a generic 404 if I try to access it while suspended

Tags: bug, profile-page, account-suspension, 404-not-found

[image]

While any of the other sections under "Edit Profile & Settings" do work normally.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that's legit. We should fix that.

Comment: @Adam LOL have I accidentally reported a legit bug? :D

Comment: I'm afraid so. Don't feel bad; we all make mistakes sometimes.

Comment: Wow, a legit bug report - must be a sign of the End Times

Comment: Ok, how many potential bugs do you have saved up from your suspension?

Comment: @AdamLear Any chance the bug will be fixed anytime soon? It's [still ongoing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332193/can-suspended-users-edit-their-profiles), and still [resulting in confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327959/edit-profile-and-settings-button-results-in-a-page-not-found-for-suspended-use).