# Can suspended users edit their profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, account-suspension

Are suspended users able to edit their profiles, or are they prohibited from doing so?

Comment: A related older post: [Why can't one update his own profile during a suspension period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294989)

Comment: See also [animuson's answer to my older question *Can a user in timed suspension edit their own posts?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297150/157730) Mad Scientist's comment on the question itself is also relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes and no. I just tested it with my sock puppet. I suspended it 'for science', and now it gets a 404 when trying to open the 'Edit profile and settings' tab on that site (this has been reported as a bug [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258745/399694)):

[image]

However, it's possible to edit *another* profile on the network and have its changes apply everywhere, thereby bypassing this restriction. ([This deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295730/295232) which I discovered later, after @Martin linked to the *question*, mentions it as well.) So this could be considered *another* [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), though it's not particularly harmful.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference - the links and all are still disabled. And any content that might be offensive would be offensive all over SE, and can be removed elsewhere.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly did you do to get suspended?

Comment: @Stormblessed His test account got suspended instead, for science.

Comment: @Sonic but I'm curious what he did to get that account suspended for science.

Comment: @Stormblessed He himself is a moderator there; he suspended his own test account.

Comment: Worth noting that the 404 page behavior [is considered a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258745/edit-profile-section-throws-a-generic-404-if-i-try-to-access-it-being-suspende), but its fix has been delayed.

Comment: @Sonic ah-hah! Mod powers are nice.

Comment: @Sonic oops I messed up: I edited in grace period what I meant to do, but didn't undo the bad part.