# "Page not found" when clicking on "edit profile" when suspended

Tags: bug, profile-page, account-suspension

Example on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/18147/franck-dernoncourt:

[image]

No problem on other SE websites where I am not suspended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Edit profile" section throws a generic 404 if I try to access it being suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258745/edit-profile-section-throws-a-generic-404-if-i-try-to-access-it-being-suspende). Also [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332193/can-suspended-users-edit-their-profiles), [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294989/why-cant-one-update-their-own-profile-during-a-suspension-period)

Comment: @ARogueAnt. on behalf of a suspended user

Comment: @ARogueAnt. If the same bug report has been filed in the past, but received no answers, it should be closed as a duplicate so as to consolidate the reports in one place. Most issue trackers close duplicate issues for the same reason.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog  I'm sure that I failed to learn that lesson before, thanks and apologies.